# Chrome 8 - Floating Table - takes 100% width available

Tags: css

Found in version 8, working fine in 7 & other browsers (even IE),

I have a table with a declared width (tried with a declaration in css/inline/attribute) and a float:right. It seems that in the page this table width takes up the entire available space (looking up with the developer instrument confirms that the table takes 100% width while the tbody takes only the width declared before)

Other floating elements near the table are cleared  over or under it.

removing the float declaration the table width returns as declared

any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bug. I have a DIV in Chrome 8 that *should* take up 100% of the container width, but does not unless specifically declared.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't solve the question re why floats would behave like that (it does sound weird), but have you considered using `display:inline-block;` instead of using floats?

Comment: removing the float solves the problem, i think it has something to do with floats and undeclared widths...

Answer (score 0):

I have a float and a declared width, but the content that should be to the left of a floating right table is clearing to below the right table. This looks like a bug in Chrome 8.